# I can't send an error message on primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF page with primefaces. How do I get an error message to occur on a failed login? I tried requiredMessage but the result is negative.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
            
                    <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name" />
                    <p:inputText id="buyerName" required="true" requiredMessage="Enter your name" />
                    

                    <h:outputLabel for="surname" value="Surname" />
                    <p:inputText id="buyerSurname" required="true" />
```

Comment: You need a component to display the message. See for example https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/validation.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
            <p:messages/>
                    <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name" />
                    <p:inputText id="buyerName" required="true" requiredMessage="Enter your name" />
                    

                    <h:outputLabel for="surname" value="Surname" />
                    <p:inputText id="buyerSurname" required="true" />
```